# jQuery - after click show one div and close other

Tags: jquery, css, html, hide, show

I'm building my personal site and I've encountered a challenge. I suppose it will be none to those, who are more familiar with jQuery than me (not hard) ;)

**The structure:**

```
<a href>one</a>
<div id="hidden_one></div>

<a href>two</a>
<div id="hidden_two></div>

<a href>three</a>
<div id="hidden_three></div>

<a href>four</a>
<div id="hidden_four></div>
```

etc.
In other words every "a" is shown all the time and has an attached div below.

**The action:**

After clicking any "a":

if clicked "a" has a shown div below - close the div

if clicked "a" doesn't have a shown div below, but there are other divs shown - hide those divs and show the one attached to this "a".

if no div is shown - show the one attached to this "a".

I'll be grateful for any support! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to use the href tag:

HTML:

```
<a href="hidden_one">one</a>
<div id="hidden_one">Hide 1</div>

<a href="hidden_two">two</a>
<div id="hidden_two">Hide 2</div>

<a href="hidden_three">three</a>
<div id="hidden_three">Hide 3</div>

<a href="hidden_four">four</a>
<div id="hidden_four">Hide 4</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $('a').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#" + href).slideToggle().siblings('div').hide();
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qTeD/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle().siblings('div').hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VyE4u/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it the easy and fast way. Or you put in some extra effort and build up good HTML and go for safe. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/qLPge/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.clickme').on('click', function(e){
       $('div.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
       $(this).next('.showme').addClass('active').fadeIn(); 
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
It works like charm :)

I've made a small modification:

```
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#" + href).slideToggle().siblings('div').slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4qTeD/2/